# Is there a way to use Typescript decorators on destructuring elements in method parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, destructuring, javascript-decorators

I am using TypeScript decorators to define the Swagger documentation of my Serverless API. Is there a way to use decorators inside the destructuring definition for my API parameters?

I've tried the obvious destructuring route, where I just define my destructured elements, and put the annotation prior to them in the object.

The following works fine.

```
@Get('{pathParam1}/myPath/{pathParam2}')
@Response<MyModel>('200', 'Model Found')
  public async handler(@Path('pathParam1') pathParam1: string, @Path('pathParam2') pathParam2: string ) {
  ...
};
```

However, I actually do not get the pathParameters like this. I get them in an event object.

I would like to do something like this

```
@Get('{pathParam1}/myPath/{pathParam2}')
@Response<MyModel>('200', 'Model Found')
  public async handler({ pathParameters: { @Path('pathParam1') pathParam1, @Path('pathParam2') pathParam2 } }: Event ) {
  ...
};
```

Where the Event type looks like the following

```
interface Event {
  pathParameters: object;
  body: any;
  headers: object;
}
```

However, the above does not properly compile in TypeScript.

I get a variety of compile time errors from TypeScript throughout the handler method, but the one on the actual method parameter itself is the following.

`Property destructuring pattern expected. ts(1180)`

Comment: Ran into a similar issue when using serverless. Was curious if you solved this?